# Powershell - finding user name and password with Microsoft Account

Tags: windows-10, powershell, passwords, scheduled-tasks, windows-hello

I have a script that sets up a scheduled task that runs with elevated privileges using powershell

```
$argument = "-WindowStyle Hidden -command `"&{$myscriptPath}`""
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument $argument
$settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -Hidden -StartWhenAvailable -RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At $scheduledTime
Write-Host "for this script to work it needs elevated privileges"

$Credentials = get-credential
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "mytask"`
    -User $Credentials.username`
    -Password $Credentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password`
    -Action $action`
    -Settings $settings`
    -Trigger $trigger`
    -RunLevel Highest`
```

It works fine on my work machine, that has a password set up (on a domain, I'm not sure if that's relevant), but at home where I'm setting up a machine that has a user who logs in with a Microsoft account / Windows Hello pin, I keep getting an error that the user/password is incorrect. If I try to manually set up the task using my login and pin combination that doesn't work either.

So the question is: what should I enter as username (or domain\username) and password when manually setting up an elevated privileges scheduled task, and how do I get that information with powershell?

Comment: Does it work when you manually set the task with the current user and password?

Comment: No. I'm not sure what user/pass to use. Is it my Microsoft account or the username for the machine (e.g. the name on my home folder)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2777388/you-cannot-schedule-tasks-by-using-a-microsoft-account-in-task-schedul) link. According to Microsoft it's not possible to setup a task in the task scheduler with a Microsoft account.

> **Cause:** This issue occurs because the Task Scheduler UI does not support
>   Microsoft accounts.
>
> **Workaround:** To work around this issue, run the Schtasks command together with the /ru and /rp options to schedule the task.